# pre-domain & domain (confusion)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In my Algebra textbook I found a sentence that confused me.

It says:
"A mapping is a function whose domain is its entire pre-domain."

Never before I found a term of pre-domain.

There is even a small ilustration, that distinguish a "domain" and "pre-domain", where pre-domain is superset of domain.

By definition of a mapping/function I know that every element of domain must has its own pair, so I can´t count that there are some unpaired elements which I can place inside pre-domain.

Now, I´m asking myself which elements I can place there.

I will be thankfull for a concrete example.

Comment: It is just a (perhaps unfortunate) terminology, don't waste too much time with it. This author distinguishes between "mappings" and "functions" but it is only his or her personal choice.

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro -Good to hear that. Thank you.

Comment: I checked. Even Google is unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Urgje -I was searching on Google, but with no success.

Comment: Can be useful to have the full ref for your textbook.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA  - I can post this link: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~alspaugh/cls/shr/correspondence.html

Comment: Thanks; it is clear that in this case the def of function $f : A \to B$ does not implies that $f(a)$ is defined for any $a \in A$. Thus any $A$ that is the superset of the *domain* is called *pre-domain*.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA - Thank you.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA and OP -- This is two examples of bad terminology in one definition, quite an achievement by the author. First, "pre-domain":  a term not used by anyone else, and then using "pre-" in an unintuitive way. What's so "pre" about a "pre-domain"? It's a *super*set of the actual domain, not something lesser or smaller. Second, hijacking the notation $f\colon A\to B$ to mean, by default, *partial* function on $A$. It's not cool to teach people conventions that they will have to *unlearn* later.

Comment: @ BrianO & MauroALLEGRANZA - Maybe a good example for "pre-domain" can be a restricted function together with restricted domain. -example. a sinus function where domain is (0, pi) while pre-domain is (set R excluding(0, pi)).